# A temporary directory that exists only during run time of user-specified code

Tags: bash

For a research analysis, I'm writing a small bash script that serves as a frontend to [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/singularity). The reason is that I want to save in this script which options are needed for singularity. For example, I want the working directory to appear at a fixed path in the container, regardless of the actual working directory path.

Singularity has the `--contain` option for this, but this requires me to manually define a temporary directory for the container. I use `mktemp` for that. After the end of the script, I use `trap` to 
delete that directory. However, I fear that there might be a corner case where `trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'` might delete the wrong directory.

The script, called `cexec`, executes an arbitrary command inside the container. For example `./cexec R` starts R inside the container.

**Is there a corner case in the following script where the script deletes a directory that it didn't create?**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Execute a command in the container
set -ue

thisdir="$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
container="rserver_200211_commitd117c677.sif" # get such a file by using `singularity pull ...`

# Create a temporary directory
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d -t cexec-XXXXXXXX)"
# We delete this directory afterwards, so its important that $tmpdir
# really has the path to an empty, temporary dir, and nothing else!
# (for example empty string or home dir)
if [[ ! "$tmpdir" || ! -d "$tmpdir" ]]; then
  echo "Error: Could not create temp dir $tmpdir"
  exit 1
fi
# check if temp dir is empty
tmpcontent="$(ls -A "$tmpdir")"
if [ ! -z "$tmpcontent" ]; then
  echo "Error: Temp dir '$tmpdir' is not empty"
  exit 1
fi
# Delete the temporary directory after the end of the script
trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'" EXIT

singularity exec \
  -B "$tmpdir:/tmp" \
  --contain \
  -H "$thisdir:/data" \
  "$container" \
  "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always set up the trap *before* trying to create the directory. Otherwise there's a race condition where the script may die after creating the directory but before having a chance to clean it up. And use single quotes for the `trap` command to make sure the variable is only expanded at exit:

```
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
```

If the trap ends up being triggered *before* `mktemp` the result is simply `rm -rf ""`, which does nothing.

Some other suggestions:

1. [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) is a more portable shebang.
2. `set -o errexit -o nounset` is more readable than `set -ue`.
3. `BASH_SOURCE` is an array, and it's only by accident that `$array_name` refers to the first element of `array_name`. `directory="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"` would be more explicit.
4. `if [[ ! "$tmpdir" || ! -d "$tmpdir" ]]` is redundant. If `mktemp` fails the script will stop there, and if it's been removed `rm -rf "$tmpdir"` is safe, as mentioned.
5. [Don't use `ls` in scripts!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/3645)
6. The temporary directory *can't* already contain any files. That's part of the contract of `mktemp` - it *will* create a new directory if it can, or fail otherwise.

Comment: I don't normally like single quotes for the `trap`, leaving the variable unexpanded (there's a risk that some other code modifies it, particularly with a generic name like that).  So I'd have something like `while tmpdir="$(mktemp -u)"; trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'" EXIT; mkdir "$tmpdir"; do : ; done`

Comment: If you're worried about something modifying `tmpdir` you can just `readonly tmpdir`.